# Fastest way to convert 16.16 fixed point to 32 bit float in c/c++ on x86?

Tags: c++, floating-point, fixed-point

Most people seem to want to go the other way. I'm wondering if there is a fast way to convert fixed point to floating point, ideally using SSE2. Either straight C or C++ or even asm would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy as long as you have a double-precision FPU: there are 53 bits of significant figures. SSE2 has double-precision.

```
float conv_fx( int32_t fx ) {
    double fp = fx;
    fp = fp / double(1<<16); // multiplication by a constant
    return fp;
}
```

Comment: This code shows how simple it really is. The major performance constraint here will be memory, not CPU. Things would be different of course if you have to convert an _array_ of fixed-points to floats.

Comment: @MSalters: Vector unpack+pack operations to convert pairs of `int32_t`s to `double`s at a time would still be the way to go to convert an array with SSE.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that but it seemed slow given its a conversion a div (or mul) and another conversion. I guess I will have to try it in various ways.

Comment: @codist: mul and 64-to-32 conversion should both be 1 cycle.

Comment: Thanks, its hard to get a brain around how fast things like this are.

Comment: Just wondering if there's a difference between `fp = fp / double(1<<16);` and `fp = ldexpf(fp, -16);` -- I have tried the later in my code.